# clojure on-demand require

Tags: clojure, require

Is there a way to put 'require' where needed e.g. inside a function. Something like this:

`(defn fun [x]
   (do (require 'clojure.string)
   ('clojure.string/split x #"\s"))
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is.

```
(defn foo
  [x]
  (require 'clojure.string)
  ((resolve 'clojure-string/split) x #"\s"))
```

Comment: @xiefei : Don't be :) because require is a just a function

Comment: @Ankur : I had thought that multiple function calls at the same level should always be wrapped in something like `do`. Should `require` be considered as side-effect? Or there is an implicit `do` here?

Comment: @xiefei The body of a function is wrapped in an implicit `do`. `require` is all about side-effects.